# Map projections used for star maps

Tags: star

I'm working on a star map program and I'm wondering what are the most common map projections used to print star maps...? I want to map of the entire visible sky from a certain point on the surface of Earth. I have all the visible stars and their Altitude-Azimuth, but I need to map this semi-sphere onto a circle in 2D.

I'd like to get something like this:

[image: Star map]

I've been playing around with equidistant and gnomonic (-1 RE) projections but they feel too distorted. What are the most common projections used for 2D, circular, entire-visible-sky star maps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stereographic projection
([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection),
[Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StereographicProjection.html))
is commonly used for all-sky maps
(e.g. [Skymaps.com](http://www.skymaps.com/),
[Your Sky](https://www.fourmilab.ch/yoursky/)).
As distance from the center of the map increases,
constellations grow larger but keep their shapes.

Comment: Stereographic worked beautifully, thanks!

Comment: Does stereographic projection works also for horizon views?

Comment: @Mr_LinDowsMac Yes, if you can accept a slightly curved horizon. If the view is very wide, a cylindrical projection may be a better choice.

Comment: I found some of your projections here: https://armchairastronautics.blogspot.com/p/skymap.html, and allows to set a horizon marker in some of them. I tried with cyllindrical stereographic, but the problem is to find the right amount of zoom of naked eye user view, there is no FOV field settting.